# "Congratulation" vs. "congratulations"

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

*Congratulation* vs. *congratulations* — which one to use? How/when?

Comment: I don't see why you should ever be a cheapskate and offer only one congratulation when it doesn't cost you any more to offer many. (The same applies to thanks and condolences.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Congratulations* is simply the plural form of *congratulation*. See these examples from the [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/congratulations) dictionary:

1. Let me offer you my congratulations for being elected.
2. Please send her my congratulations.
3. I sent her a letter of congratulations.

**The plural form illustrated by the examples above is much more used than the singular form**:

2523 matches for *congratulations* vs. 56 matches for *congratulation* in the [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/).

It should be noted that the less common singular form can be found in sentences where the plural form would not apply. See these examples extracted from the COCA:

1. ...notes of congratulation and consolation.
2. The Artistic Podiatrist extended a hand in congratulation.
3. I made conventional sound of congratulation.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear for me and the link to COCA.

Comment: It's parallel to "wish". You can make a wish, but what you offer to people is "best wishes". Similarly "condolences", "commiserations". Not, however *"appreciations". Go figure.

Answer (score 5):

Although Bruno's examples are quite correct, I have very rarely seen the singular "congratulation" used in practical English. Any time you refer to offering someone congratulations you use the plural and I think you could easily pass yourself off as a native English speaker without ever using the singular.

Comment: Offering only one congratulation would be interpreted as damning with faint praise.