# “I would like to express a big congratulations...” Why ‘a’ before the plural form?

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

At school I was taught that before the plural form we don't use the articles *a* and *an*. So why do people use *a* before *big congratulations*?

Examples:

- ***A Big Congratulations*** to Dr. Wei Cheng on His Latest Publication! [link](http://ufh.com.cn/center-for-clinical-research/announcements/a-big-congratulations-to-dr-wei-cheng-on-his-latest-publication/)
- ***A big congratulations*** to the Devs!
  They have put in an incredible amount of work this week to get this online up and running for all of us. They have handled communication with the community perfectly keeping us up to date ... [link](http://datehttps://steamcommunity.com/app/386940/discussions/0/405694115206485646/)
- ***A big congratulations!***
  We would like to say a massive congratulations to ‘Stumble’ and ‘Tripp’ for successfully completing a five day residential to become qualified regional Makaton trainers! [link](http://www.gibsideschool.org/a-big-congratulations/)
- ***A Big Congratulations!***
  Further to our article last month, we wanted to congratulate Jane Mason and Tom Wicks on their effort in Nottingham Life Cycle 5. Jane and her team completed her 50 miles, while Tom finished his 75 miles in the aid of raising money for dementia research. [link](https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/mathematics/news/a-big-congratulations!-.aspx)
- ***A big congratulations*** to Hozier from Artists Den and Chase Sapphire Preferred for being nominated for "Favorite Artist- Alternative Rock" by the American Music Awards. [link](https://web.facebook.com/chase/photos/a.608041632555131.1073741825.603730309652930/1220577111301577/?type=1&theater)

plus many more found on the Internet.

Comment: Redefine "people", I know of no English-speaking person who would say that.

Comment: By "people" I mean 471.000 results in Google when I type "a big congratulations".

Comment: Then provide the link - and don't forget that Google often gives results that do *not exactly match* your requested phrase.  E.g. Did Google ignore the "a" part of your search term?

Comment: Despite what you (think you) found via Google, the short answer is that nobody who is speaking even semi-grammatical English would say "a big congratulations". If you think you have found evidence to the contrary, please [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/329670/edit) your question and include said evidence.

Comment: Well actually when I search google for the phrase I do get about 471,000 results, and "only" about 541,000 when I remove the "a". I'm not sure the numerous people apparently using this turn of phrase know what "to congratulate" means, though.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that maybe this is some kind of mistake which for some reason is being copied by other people and that's why we have so many results. But I believe that it should be just "big congrats" and that's it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I wonder if it's transferred usage from the phrase "a big thank-you", where the article is not incorrect.

Comment: I wonder if the sound of "our" in "express our huge congratulations" could be mistaken for "a", and copied; by native speakers too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term **congratulation** remains a noun whether it is used as an interjection or not. The term *love* in the exclamation, “Love you!” is still a verb, so I cannot help but disagree with @Spencer's analysis

However, it is interesting that **congratulations** is far more common  than the singular *congratulation*. To say to someone *Congratulation on your wedding!* would be odd, but if you send someone *a letter of congratulation* that is acceptable.

From (my hard copy) Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary

> **congratulation** /kənˌɡrætʃuˈleɪʃn/ *noun* **1** [U] the action of congratulating sb or of being congratulated: *a speech of congratulation for the winner*. **2 congratulations** [pl] (**a**) words of congratulation: *offer sb one's congratulations on his sucess.*  (**b**) (also *infml* **congrats**) (used as an interjection): *Congratulations on passing your driving test!*

My dictionary also informs me that the indefinite article ***a*** is used with **an abstract uncountable noun** when it is preceded by an adjective, e.g. *We're looking for someone with **a good knowledge** of German*.

Consequently, *a big* (and also *a great big*) is often collocated with *welcome*, and *thank you*, e.g.

- ***[A big welcome](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search1?word=welcome)*** to our special guest,...
- **[a big thank you](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=thank%20you)** to the hospital staff*

and the fixed expressions:

- **a** great **many**
- **a** good **many**
- **a** few **people**

are perfectly idiomatic in English, although ‘**a**’ precedes a plural noun.

I think native speakers would say *a big congratulation* if the singular form was idiomatic when congratulating someone, but it's simply not. Although the following are commonly said and heard in speeches, they do sound a little formal.

- Our **[warmest congratulations](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22warmest+congratulations%22&tbm=bks) ...**
- *My* ***[heartiest congratulations](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22heariest%20congratulations%22&oq=%22heariest%20congratulations%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.17295j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22heartiest%20congratulations%22&tbm=bks)*** *on your promotion*

Native speakers are just used to using the plural noun form

see also: ["Congratulation" vs. "congratulations"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/congratulation-vs-congratulations)

Comment: So I assume that "a big congrats" acts the similar way as "a big thank you" and the "big contracts" is considered singular because we think of an (one) act of congratulating rather than many congrats in the plural.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzkup  Yes, I would say "a big congrats" is an even more informal way of congratulating someone, although I don't say it myself, I do hear *congrats* being used. I think the "a big + Noun" is a very common collocation, we have: "a big round of applause", "a big thank you", "a big day / deal / hug..." etc. but congratulation, in the singular form, is becoming rare in speech. Perhaps in writing it is still used.

Comment: I suppose it is a very informal way of saying  " [a good] Many congratulations"

Comment: Thank you Mari-Lou! So I'll just stick to saying "Big congratulations" or "Many congratulations" (without "a") to be correct both in speaking and writing.

Comment: If you want to avoid using the indefinite article, then saying  *warmest / heartiest / many congratulations* would be best.

Comment: The difference is that "congratulations!" becomes singular when used as an interjection.  Nothing in @Mari-Lou's response changes this.  Quantifiers like "good" and "few" singularize the plural noun.  "Big" does not.  One might say _a big people_, but in that case, you're changing the meaning of _people_.

Answer (score 5):

Just another one of those crazy things to trip over in English: A word that looks like one part of speech but is really a different one.

> *I would like to offer a big "Congratulations!"* to Bill and Sasha.

The word *congratulations* here isn't a noun; instead, it's an *[interjection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection)*, made into a quotation and then stuck in a sentence in place of a noun.

This interjection is a shortened form of a whole sentence (e.g. "Congratulations to you!" with the "to you" part elided.)

The speaker is saying, in a roundabout way, that he would like to say "Congratulations!". Once. Thus making the article necessary.

The speaker could have said

> *A big "Way to go!"* to Bill and Sasha

or, less awkwardly,

> I would like to offer *my congratulations* to Bill and Sasha.

instead.

Comment: A big thank you for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

In this case saying "big congrats" would seem to indicate that you are giving multiple "congrats". The "a" before the phrase shows that you gave exactly one "big congrats", or gave told them "congratulations" in a big way only once.

Comment: Nobody ever gives anybody a *"congratulation"*. That would be way too stingy. Ditto for a *"thank"*.

Comment: Lol well I'll give you a prop for that comment. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I just faced this situation of A before congratulations with S. I graduated from a US university, received a letter from the dean with that expression (I would like to personally extend a sincere congratulations), and emailed my advisor to have the dean's secretary fix what I thought to be typo sent to hundreds of students, if not thousands since the university started. To my surprise, the dean emailed me directly few minutes ago and stated that it was the correct form used throughout the world...
I don't doubt it but I couldn't help looking it up.

PS: I live in the US but am a native French speaker.

Comment: You should doubt it.

Answer (score -2):

I'm a native English speaker, and here are my thoughts:

This expression is chiefly British-English and, although technically wrong, is commonly used throughout the UK. Sadly, there are many phrases we use when speaking that would sound wrong to someone whose expertise is English as a second language.

An example and frequently used expression is the word and use of "sat" instead of "sitting".

We British often use "sat" in the following ways, "we were sat", "when you're sat for two hours on a hard bench, it's a killer" or "I was sat over there".

The above three examples wouldn't sound wrong to most native English speakers because they're used in speech so often that they sound correct when, in fact, "sitting / was sitting" should've been used instead.

Comment: As an American, I can assure you that this is _not_ chiefly British English.