# Some compliment nouns are always plural, but other have singular forms - why?

Tags: nouns, pluralia-tantum

Some compliment nouns like congratulations, best wishes, thanks, or cheers are always plural in form, but I have seen singular forms like "congratulate  them" or "thank them".

In these 'thank' and 'congratulate' are singular. Why?
Does 'cheers' or 'best wishes' also have singular form?

Comment: When you are complementing someone it seems inappropriate to limit your complement to only one.  Likewise when wishing someone well -- would you give only one good wish?

Comment: Related question: [“I would like to express a big congratulations…” Why ‘a’ before the plural form?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/329670/80039)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *congratulate* in the phrase "congratulate them" acts as a verb, not a noun.

As a verb, *congratulates* is not the plural of *congratulate*. The trailing "s" signifies singular agreement, and the form without a trailing "s" signifies plural agreement:

- Jack (singular) *congratulates* Jill.
- They (plural) *congratulate* each other.

Likewise for *cheer* and *wish*.

Comment: When you _thank_ (verb) someone, you give _thanks_ (plural noun) to them. We never speak of _a thank_.